# iOS 8 UI Alert View

Tags: ios8, uialertview

UI alert view and toolbar is getting dislocated for iOS 8. This occurs only if we move from a horizontal view to portrait view.[image: ePlease r]

![Screen shot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF6zi.png)

Comment: Thanks for telling us that you have an issue (Not that I understand what your issue is) but what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

in iOS8 system provide a new class `UIAlertController`,A `UIAlertController` object displays an alert message to the user. This class replaces the UIActionSheet and UIAlertView classes for displaying alerts.
UIActionSheet and UIAlertView is UIView subclass，i guess iOS8 adjust screen rotate logic，so you need use `UIAlertController` in iOS8 and after。this a class will help you https://github.com/wangyangcc/FYAlertManage